# Getting 404 for MockMVC instead of 200 for embedded H2 Test Class

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-data-jpa, junit5

I have a Spring boot Java Project where I am trying to run functional tests using an embedded H2 server

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {JPAConfig.class, OpenAPI2SpringBoot.class})
@Import(BookApiDelegateImpl.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AddBoookTest {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }


    @Test
    @Sql({"/book-schema.sql"})
    void addBook() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/book")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .characterEncoding("UTF-8")
                .content("{\"book\": \"LOTR\"}")
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
    }

}
```

When I run this I am getting 404 error, instead of getting 200 I am getting 404 error. There are no 404 exceptions thrown.

Want to check if any changes are required in annotations?

Comment: Remove the `@Import` and only ad `@SpringBootTest` (without the `classes` property!). Just `@Autowired` the `MockMvc` and ditch your setup method. Then re-run.

Comment: Cannot remove @SpringBootTest classes. `JPAConfig` contains Embedded H2 beans and `OpenAPISpringApplication` contains Spring Boot Main Application (I have 2 MainApplication)

Comment: Why not use `@ AutoConfigureTestDatabase` instead of your `JPAConfig`? Weird design to have 2 main classes. Well leave that in remove the rest (apart from `@ AutoConfigureMockMvc`).